# How do i get a loop to keep looping until it has checked all index's of an array, while using a random number generator to check the specific index?

Tags: c++

I am working on a Tic Tac Toe assignment for my class. And I cannot get the while loop to keep looping after it takes in a search number thats already been removed from the Array. Example ;
string array[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",} ;
if I search for a 5, and it is in there still, it will change it to a "X". But if I search for a 5 again, it will quit the entire loop instead of just asking for another input. I need it to keep asking for an input and keep checking the input until the entire array has been changed to X's and O's.

I have tried a for loop, while loop, and even bools to keep the loop going until all values have been changed. but nothing is working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string array[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

    string search;
    bool found = true;
    bool keeprunning = true;

    while (keeprunning) {
        // for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        while (found) {
            cout << "Enter a character to search for: ";
            getline(cin, search);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                cout << "Items in the array " << array[i] << endl;

                if (search == array[i]) {
                    found = true;
                    array[i] = "X";
                    cout << "\nPresent" << endl;
                    cout << array[i] << endl;
                    break;
                }
                if (i == 4) { // i has to be set to 1 less than the size of the array, so that it only fires after
                    // the array has been scanned through and the inputted value hasn't been found.
                    cout << "\nNOT PRESENT.\n";
                    found = false;

                    break;
                }
                if (search != array[0] && search != array[1] && search != array[2] && search != array[3] && search != array[4]) {
                    keeprunning = false;
                    cout << "\n\nThere are no more available places to change\n\n";
                }
                cout << "New array data\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    cout << array[i] << " ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code is very confused (and I'm a little confused about exactly what you are trying to do). You need to do one thing at a time. So when you are writing a loop to find an item, that loop should do that **and only that**. Then **after** the find loop has finished you should change your array or print `NOT PRESENT`. If you organise your code like that you will find that it simplifies things a lot.

Comment: Sorry, your indentation is too inconsistent for me. I think I finally found the loop you are talking about, but it took too long. Perhaps a [mre] would work better? Skip the user input, and just repeatedly search for `5`. Or even skip the search and assume an 'X' was found. You don't need to prove your array handling skills, just demonstrate the code that should cause the loop to repeat but instead breaks out of the loop.

Comment: Another tip is to split your code into functions, so that each function does one job. You will be surprised at how much having a function with a single purpose and a clear descriptive name makes it easier to write the rest of your code.

Comment: The for loop should be replaced by something like `auto pos = std::find(std::begin(array), std::end(array), search); if (pos == std::end(array)) { ...handle input not in array... } else { ...handle input in array... }`. Alternatively using a `std::set<std::string>` may be a good choice which would allow you to check for presence of an element in the a set `s` via `s.count(search) != 0`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the while (keeprunning) loop is adding nothing to the solution. You should take that out.

What's happening is that when you search for a string that is not in the array (e.g. because it has been overwritten with an X) you set `found = false`. This means that `while (found)` at the top of the loop is no longer true, so the loop (including prompting the user to input a number) stops running.

Without fully understanding your requirement I suspect you need to do 3 things:

1. Think about how you DO want to terminate the loop, otherwise, your program could run forever. For example, if you input (for example) a `q` (for quit) you could detect that, perform a break, and exit the loop.
2. Look into using `continue` instead of `break`. A `continue` instruction stops executing further code within the loop and goes around the loop again.
3. Use a `do-while` loop instead of a `while` loop. A `do-while` loop executes at least once and tests whether it should go round again at the bottom of the loop. A `while` loop depends on some condition being true - that's why you had to initialise the value of found to be true.